# 引数の数値に応じて実行する処理を増やしたい

Tags: lua

少し前にluaを始めた初心者なのですが、条件分岐について詳しく知りたいので質問させていただきます。

とあるプログラムを書いていたところ下記のようなことをさせたいと思ったのですが、そのままifなどで書くと凄まじい長さになったしまうので何かいい方法はないでしょうか？

引数が1の時はA
2の時はAとB
3の時はAとBとC
4の時はAとBとCとD…
と言った感じです。
ただし実際はAとかBとかといった部分に規則性がありません。

今のコードは以下のものです。

```
color_set1 = colors.combine(colors.white)
color_set2 = colors.combine(colors.white, colors.orange)
color_set3 = colors.combine(colors.white, colors.orange, colors.magenta)
color_set4 = colors.combine(colors.white, colors.orange, colors.magenta, colors.lightBlue)
color_set5 = colors.combine(colors.white, colors.orange, colors.magenta, colors.lightBlue, colors.yellow)
color_set6 = colors.combine(colors.white, colors.orange, colors.magenta, colors.lightBlue, colors.yellow, colors.lime)


function RS(nmb)
    local cmd = {}
    cmd["1"] = "\"left\",color_set1"
    cmd["2"] = "\"left\",color_set2"
    cmd["3"] = "\"left\",color_set3"
    cmd["4"] = "\"left\",color_set4"
    cmd["5"] = "\"left\",color_set5"
    cmd["6"] = "\"left\",color_set6"
    cmd["7"] = "\"top\",color_set1"
    cmd["8"] = "\"top\",color_set2"
    cmd["9"] = "\"top\",color_set3"
    cmd["10"] = "\"top\",color_set4"
    cmd["11"] = "\"top\",color_set5"
    cmd["12"] = "\"top\",color_set6"
    cmd["13"] = "\"back\",color_set1"
    cmd["14"] = "\"back\",color_set2"
    cmd["15"] = "\"back\",color_set3"
    cmd["16"] = "\"back\",color_set4"
    cmd["17"] = "\"back\",color_set5"
    cmd["18"] = "\"back\",color_set6"
    cmd["19"] = "\"bottom\",color_set1"
    cmd["20"] = "\"bottom\",color_set2"
    cmd["21"] = "\"bottom\",color_set3"
    cmd["22"] = "\"bottom\",color_set4"
    cmd["23"] = "\"bottom\",color_set5"
    cmd["24"] = "\"bottom\",color_set6"
    cmd["25"] = "\"front\",color_set1"
    cmd["26"] = "\"front\",color_set2"
    cmd["27"] = "\"front\",color_set3"
    cmd["28"] = "\"front\",color_set4"
    cmd["29"] = "\"front\",color_set5"
    cmd["30"] = "\"front\",color_set6"

    if nmb <= 6 then
        rs.setBundledOutput(cmd[nmb])
    elseif nmb >= 7 and nmb <= 12 then
        rs.setBundledOutput(cmd[6])
        rs.setBundledOutput(cmd[nmb])
    elseif nmb >= 13 and nmb <= 18 then
        rs.setBundledOutput(cmd[6])
        rs.setBundledOutput(cmd[12])
        rs.setBundledOutput(cmd[nmb])
    elseif nmb >= 19 and nmb <= 24 then
        rs.setBundledOutput(cmd[6])
        rs.setBundledOutput(cmd[12])
        rs.setBundledOutput(cmd[18])
        rs.setBundledOutput(cmd[nmb])
    elseif nmb >= 25 and nmb <= 30 then
        rs.setBundledOutput(cmd[6])
        rs.setBundledOutput(cmd[12])
        rs.setBundledOutput(cmd[18])
        rs.setBundledOutput(cmd[24])
        rs.setBundledOutput(cmd[nmb])
    end
end
```

Comment: コードを拝見しますと規則性がある様に見受けられますので、https://pastebin.com/DvyCet4Z の様に書いてみました。

Comment: @metropolis ありがとうございます！参考にさせていただきます。

Comment: @PicoSushi 様、@metropolis 様、@mjy 様 ご丁寧な説明ありがとうございました！まだまだ初心者なので度々質問をするかもしれませんが、どうぞよろしくお願いします。本当にご回答くださり、ありがとうございました。

Comment: mjy様 タイトル編集ありがとうございます！

Comment: nekketsuuu様 質問文の編集ありがとうございます！

Answer (score 1, accepted):

先頭のN個の要素に何か行なうのだと考えました。下は `print` する例です。

```lua
function print_first_n(list, n)
    for i,v in ipairs(list) do
        if i > n then
            break
        end
        print(v)
    end
end

local choices =  {"A", "B", "C", "D"}
print_first_n(choices, 3)
--[[ 出力:
A
B
C
--]]
```

先頭のN個の要素を引数として一度だけ関数を実行するなら下のようにできます。

```
function print_once_first_n(list, n)
    print(table.unpack(list, 1, n))
end

local choices =  {"A", "B", "C", "D"}
print_once_first_n(choices, 3)
--[[出力
A   B   C
--]]
```

参考: [table.unpack](http://milkpot.sakura.ne.jp/lua/lua53_manual_ja.html#pdf-table.unpack)、[Multiple Results（英語）](http://www.lua.org/pil/5.1.html)

Comment: 素晴らしい回答ありがとうございます。このコードを一部書き換えて私のプログラムに使わせていただいてもよろしいでしょうか？

Comment: @Minetake 基本的にこの程度のコードの断片に著作権はないと考えます。
しかしご心配かも知れないので、この投稿のコードに関していかなる著作権も主張しないと明言いたします。
（スタック・オーバーフローへの投稿内容で著作権が発生する部分に関しての一般的な内容は、[投稿した内容のライセンスは?](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/licensing) をご覧下さい）